# Porque no me levanta las vistas desde el template (DJANGO)?

Tags: django, django-templates

estoy creando un proyecto y a la hora de configurar el settings como debe ser, no me levanta. He  creado correctamente tanto la carpeta (dentro del proyecto raiz) como el archivo. Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradezco. Adjunto dos capturas. saludos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

adjunto imagen del settings, me parece que esta bien configurado

[image: imagen del settings]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).